# Firebase Cloud Function: How to fail a retryable event without causing a cold start?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Given a Firebase Cloud Function, what's the proper way to fail an event (with the intention of retrying it) **without causing a cold start**?

[This documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors) suggests that unhandled errors cause cold starts. When using `async` functionality I'm assuming this applies to a rejected `Promise` as well.

> throw new Error('I failed you'); // Will cause a cold start if not caught

Given that functions will often rely on third-party services that may not be 100% reliable, I don't want my functions to incur further penalties from cold starts due to transient downstream errors.

Is this even a recommended strategy? I'm using Firestore so I've considered storing retryable events in a temp collection that is scraped by a scheduled cloud function, but this seems unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rejected promise on its own is not an "unhandled error".  What you're showing is a thrown exception and doesn't have anything directly to do with promises.  A thrown exception that's escapes the function callback is considered unhandled.  If you need to knowingly fail the function invocation, just **return a rejected promise**, don't **throw** anything as your quoted example code is doing now.

A simple rejected promise can be created if necessary using [Promise.reject()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject):

```
return Promise.reject(new Error('fail'))
```

Comment: Will `return Promise.reject(new Error('fail'))` without `.catch` cause a cold start? Because I doing this in my function, It shows `Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.`, So seems system treat `Promise.reject(new Error('fail'))` as unhandle as well?